# Laravel validating an integer, but getting a validation error must be an integer

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I am trying to validate a phone number.  First I strip the '-' out then I convert the inputed string to an integer.  When I try to validate the integer I get an error that the input must be an integer.  However, I just converted the string to and integer.  Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?

Here is my code

```
$request->val = str_replace('-', '', $request->val);
                Log::debug($request->val);
                Log::debug(gettype($request->val)); //outputs string
                $request->val = intval($request->val);
                Log::debug(gettype($request->val));//outputs integer
                $this->validate($request, [
                    'val' => 'Integer|min:10|max:15'//Get an error must be interget
                ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `->merge` to alter the value of a `request` attribute, do not attempt to mutate it directly, as the state will not be saved:

```
$request->merge(['val', intval(str_replace('-', '', $request->val))]);
```